# generating sequential week numbers in multi year data (not week within a year)

Tags: python, datetime

I am relatively new to python and pandas.  I have daily count data for a range of dates that spans multiple years.  The data sources are a bit uneven in their diligence so daily trends are less useful.  Weekly summaries smooth out most of the bumps.

So I want to generate sequential week numbers from daily dates and then proceed to generate weekly  info using groupby.

I can get sequential day numbers using datetime arithmetic.  How can I get it into a form that allows me to do the following?
dfBoth['week'] = (dfBoth['DaysDiff']) // 7

Note that weeks can span consecutive years so methods providing week number within year are no help.

Here is my current code:

```
print("create sequential week number since first Sunday in 21st century")
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)  ## string -> datetime
df['BaseDate'] = pd.to_datetime('01/02/2000', infer_datetime_format=True) ## datetime of basedate
df['DaysDiff'] = (df['dt'] - df['BaseDate']).dt.days  ## days since base date
# how to convert to integer or other form that allows the following:
     df['week'] = df['DaysDiff'] // 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I Apologize for submitting this question.  Earlier versions of the code had generated values of a type that did not allow division.  I had "cleaned it up" for submission to make the question "clearer" and in doing so solved the problem.

df.dtypes tells me that the DaysDiff column generated by my submitted code is type int64, which can be divided.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).